# Deleting at some position in a double linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am having some trouble with this function I wrote to delete at some position in a double linked list. I feel like I am leaking memory and I am not doing this property for a double linked list.

Here is the code:

```
template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deletePosition(int pos) {
    Node* prev = new Node;
    Node* current = head;

    for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    prev->next = current->next;
}
```

This is pretty much what I did for a single linked list so I know this is not right. If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this for a double linked list I would really appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

I think this works correctly now:

```
    template <class T>
    void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deletePosition(int pos) {
        Node* temp = nullptr;
        Node* current = head;

        for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
            temp = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        temp->previous = current->previous;
        temp->next = current->next;
    }
```

Here is the entire code:

```
#ifndef DoubleLinkedLists_h
#define DoubleLinkedLists_h

template <class T>
class DoubleLinkedLists {
private:

    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    // Constructors
    DoubleLinkedLists() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}                  // empty constructor
    DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists const& value);                     // copy constructor
    DoubleLinkedLists<T>(DoubleLinkedLists<T>&& move) noexcept;            // move constuctor
    DoubleLinkedLists<T>& operator=(DoubleLinkedLists&& move) noexcept;    // move assignment operator
    ~DoubleLinkedLists();                                                  // destructor

    // Overload operators
    DoubleLinkedLists& operator=(DoubleLinkedLists const& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, DoubleLinkedLists<T> const& data) {
        data.display(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Member functions
    void swap(DoubleLinkedLists& other) noexcept;
    void push(const T& theData);
    void push(T&& theData);
    void display(std::ostream& str) const;
    void insertHead(const T& theData);
    void insertTail(const T& theData);
    void insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData);
    void deleteHead();
    void deleteTail();
    void deletePosition(int pos);
    bool search(const T& x);
};

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists const& value) : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
    for(Node* loop = value->head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        push(loop->data);
    }
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists<T>&& move) noexcept : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
    move.swap(*this);
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>& DoubleLinkedLists<T>::operator=(DoubleLinkedLists<T> &&move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::~DoubleLinkedLists() {
    while(head != nullptr) {
        deleteHead();
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::swap(DoubleLinkedLists<T> &other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(head,other.head);
    swap(tail,other.tail);
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::push(const T& theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->previous = tail;

    if(head == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
    }
    tail = newNode;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::push(T&& theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->previous = tail;

    if(head == nullptr) {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = newNode;
    }
    tail = newNode;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::display(std::ostream &str) const {
    for(Node* loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertHead(const T &theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->next = head;
    head->previous = newNode;
    head = newNode;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertTail(const T &theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->previous = tail;
    tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T &theData) {
    if (pos < 0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("pos is not a valid index");
    }

    Node* current = head;
    Node* previous = nullptr;

    while(pos-- > 0) {
        if(!current) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("pos is not a valid index");
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;

    newNode->previous = previous;
    newNode->next = current;

    if(newNode->previous) {
        newNode->previous->next = newNode;
    }
    else {
        head = newNode;
    }

    if(newNode->next) {
        newNode->next->previous = newNode;
    }
    else {
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deleteHead() {
    if (head != nullptr) {
        Node* old = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete old;
    }
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("the list is empty!");
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deleteTail() {
    if(head != nullptr) {
        Node* prev = nullptr;
        Node* current =  head;
        while(current->next != nullptr) {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        tail = prev;
        prev->next = nullptr;
        delete current;
    }
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("The list is already empty, nothing to delete.");
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deletePosition(int pos) {
    Node* temp = nullptr;
    Node* current = head;

    for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    temp->previous = current->previous;
    temp->next = current->next;
}

template <class T>
bool DoubleLinkedLists<T>::search(const T &x) {
    Node* current = head;
    while(current != nullptr) {
        if(current->data == x) {
            return true;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return false;
}
#endif /* DoubleLinkedLists_h */
```

And here is the main.cpp file that tests it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DoubleLinkedLists.h"



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// Double Linked List //////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    DoubleLinkedLists<int> obj;
    obj.push(2);
    obj.push(4);
    obj.push(6);
    obj.push(8);
    obj.push(10);
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Displaying All nodes---------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Inserting At Start----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insertHead(50);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-----------------Inserting At End-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insertTail(20);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-------------Inserting At Particular--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insertPosition(5,60);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Deleting At Start-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.deleteHead();
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Deleting At End-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.deleteTail();
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"--------------Deleting At Particular--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.deletePosition(5);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    obj.search(8) ? printf("Yes"):printf("No");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Node` in a method that is designed to remove one? You are definitely leaking memory because you are calling `new Node` and then just dropping it on the floor, you don't need that `new` at all. You also need to `delete` the `Node` you are removing.

Comment: should it just be nullptr then?

Comment: Why do you have `prev` in the first place?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx - yes. I don't know if you are coming from a Java or C# or some other type of garbage collected language background, but in C++, if you call `new` then you are dynamically allocating memory, which you are now responsible to manage (i.e. call `delete` when you are cleaning it up), so if you have a pointer that you need to initialize, then you set it to `nullptr` and only call `new` when you actually need a new object.

Comment: @pstrjds no no I am a mathematician by education but just trying to get my C++ skills up to snuff. Am I updating my links though correctly if I just set prev = nullptr?

Comment: As far as the question - `this is what I did for singly linked list...`, think about the difference between the two.  Singly linked is one directional, doubly linked is bi-directional.  In the singly linked case, when removing a node, you fix up the next pointer so that it points to the next node instead of the one you are removing. What would be different in the case of the doubly linked/bi-directional case?

Comment: @pstrjds I would need to make sure the nodes before and after the node deleted would need to be linked together.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx - exactly, so in the shown code you are only fixing up the next pointer, so you also need to do a similar operation to fix up the previous pointer.  Unrelated side note - my degree is in Mathematics as well :)

Comment: @pstrjds Oh nice how did you learn how to code in C++? I am basically just teaching myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173689/discussion-between-pstrjds-and-snorrlaxxx).

Comment: "*Am I updating my links though correctly*" - how are we supposed to be able to tell if you don't even show us your data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would need to do something like this. Note that your code does not handle the case of an index out of range (i.e. the position specified is either negative or is longer the list). It looked like you don't maintain a count of your list length (in the linked code) so I added a check for `current != nullptr` into the for loop as well as after the for loop to handle the case of the `pos` being longer than the list.  In that case, now the code will do nothing, but you could throw an out of range exception or something like that to indicate the invalid condition.  In the case of removing the head you also need to take care to fix up the head pointer.  I am assuming you might have a tail pointer as well, so you need to add checks to see if you are removing the tail and fix that up as well.

**Note**
I didn't compile this and so there may be a typo or two, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

```
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deletePosition(int pos) {
    if (pos < 0) {} // Should do something in this case
    Node* current = head;

    // Added null check to keep from continuing past the end of the list
    for(int i = 1; i < pos && current != nullptr; i++) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current != nullptr)
    {
        // If we are at the head, there isn't a previous
        if (current != head)
        {
            current->previous->next = current->next;
        }
        else
        {
            // In this case, we are removing the head, need to reset head to the next Node
            head = current->next;
        }

        if (current->next != nullptr)
        {
            current->next->previous = current->previous;
        }
        else if (current == tail)
        {
            // In this case we are removing the tail, need to reset tail pointer
            tail = current->previous;
        }

        delete current; // Cleans up the node we are deleting
    }
}
```